# Azure CustomScript Extension not executed in Centos 7.2

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I want to kick of below script after VM gets deployed, followed instruction provided in below URL and uploaded script and command to execute in Portal

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/

Here is my command in shell script

```
{
    cd /tmp && wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm 
yum install ansible -y 

{
```

After VM ins deployed, i cant see the script inside the VM also not font the script inside the VM

Then i added command  `mkdir /tmp/test` to create folder as part of deployment, with this deployment taking more than 5 minute and i cant see the folder /tmp/test created inside the VM,

Also observed this error in boot log

```
2017/02/06 22:55:49.085043 INFO Gateway:None
2017/02/06 22:55:49.089684 INFO Routes:None
2017/02/06 22:56:11.662445 WARNING Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
2017/02/06 22:56:11.678998 ERROR Event: name=WALinuxAgent, op=, message=Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
2017/02/06 22:56:37.728636 WARNING Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
2017/02/06 22:56:37.745898 ERROR Event: name=WALinuxAgent, op=, message=Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
2017/02/06 22:57:02.794418 WARNING Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
2017/02/06 22:57:02.810250 ERROR Event: name=WALinuxAgent, op=, message=Exception retrieving extension handlers: (000008)/var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing.
```

Seeing this error under extension

[image]

Comment: When you run extension task, the VM should be running. Please ensure your VM is running firstly and try to unistall the extension, install the extension again.

Comment: I am adding extension while creating the VM itself, any idea why it's failing that time? and to work I need to uninstall and install manually

Comment: You could check log in `/var/log/waagent.log`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I test in my lab. You had better adjust the script format. The following script is mine, it works for me.

```
cd /tmp 
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm 
yum install ansible -y
```

When you don't get expected outcome, you could check `/var/log/waagent.log`, you will get log as below:

```
2017/02/07 01:49:53 CustomScriptForLinux started to handle.
2017/02/07 01:49:53 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] cwd is /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1
2017/02/07 01:49:53 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Change log file to /var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log
2017/02/07 01:49:54.508725 INFO Event: name=Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux, op=Install, message=Launch command succeeded: customscript.py -install
2017/02/07 01:49:54.518685 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Enable extension.
2017/02/07 01:49:54.541244 INFO [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux-1.5.2.1] Launch command:customscript.py -enable
```

Now, you could check log `/var/log/azure/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.CustomScriptForLinux/1.5.2.1/extension.log`

Update: If you lost some file, you could try to uninstall the extension and install it again.
[image]

Comment: also i cant see the file /var/lib/waagent/ExtensionsConfig.2.xml is missing. failures due to this missing file

Comment: @RayeesNamathponnan I check in my VM, I have the file. Do you delete it? If possible, you could try to copy it from other VM.

Comment: I didn't deleted, its new VM, i tried multiple times always getting the same issue

Comment: @RayeesNamathponnan Could you try to uninstall CustomScriptForLinux Extension on Azure Portal and try to install it again.

Comment: I test in my lab, once extension task is created, the ExtensionConfig.*.xml is created.

Comment: Uninstall and install work,  what could be the issue first time ? i dont want to uninstall and install manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135015/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-rayees-namathponnan).

Comment: I just test in my lab. crating VM and executing extension task are two different tasks. When VM is create successful and the extension task begins to run.